# Convert a string to a hierarchyid in C#

Tags: c#, t-sql, hierarchyid

I need to be able to convert a string to a hierarchyid in c#.net - I cannot use stored procedures.

When I pass in the path (string) the query fails as the path is stored like this '/' instead of /

Can I convert it to another type?

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT Structure (Path,Description,ParentID) " +
    "VALUES(" + path + ".GetDescendant(" + lastChildPath +
    ", NULL) " +
    ",@description, @parentId", _connection);
```

**-- BitKFu**

I have added the and this is the sql query it produces:

```
CommandText = "INSERT Structure (Path,Description,ParentID) VALUES(CAST(/ AS hierarchyid).GetDescendant(NULL, NULL) ,@description, @parentId"
```

I get the following error: ex = {"Incorrect syntax near '/'."}

**-- ck**

This is what I am expecting

```
"INSERT Structure (Path,Description,ParentID) VALUES(/.GetDescendant(NULL, NULL) ,'Test', 1"
```

**-- Paul Ruane**

I have looked at this page already but it didnt really help, unless I overlooked something?

Thanks

Clare

Comment: Example input and output would be useful...

Comment: [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677209.aspx) may help.

Comment: You have to quote the / , like '/'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to cast it, if only the '' is wrong.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT Structure (Path,Description,ParentID) " +
    "VALUES(CAST('"+path+"' AS hierarchyid).GetDescendant(" + lastChildPath +
    ", NULL) " +
    ",@description, @parentId", _connection);
```

Comment: Thanks BitKFu - it did need the quotes

Comment: try to cast again, I think you missed the quoting.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old, and has an answer, but wanted to add another option since I ran into this question trying to do the same thing.

You can convert from a string to a HierarchyId in C# by using the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types namespace and something like either:

`SqlHierarchyId hierarchyIdRepresentation = (SqlHierarchyId)Convert.ChangeType(input, typeof(SqlHierarchyId))`

or

`SqlHierarchyId hierarchyIdRepresentation = SqlHierarchyId.Parse(input)`

The `.Parse()` method is called automatically anytime there is a conversion from a string and the `.ToString()` method of the `SqlHierarchyId` type overrides the standard string operator to return the canonical representation.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlhierarchyid_methods(v=sql.105).aspx